# Hide HTML element in odoo 14

Tags: python, html, odoo, odoo-14

I'm new to Odoo and I'm trying to hide HTML elements on text type field. Here is my code

```
                <style type="text/css">
                    .demo-table3 th,
                    .demo-table3 td {
                        width:1000px;
                        padding:20px;
                        top: 50%;
                        left: 50%;
                        margin-top: -120px;
                        margin-left: -220px;
                        text-align: center;
                        border: 0px;
                        padding: 7px 17px;
                    }

                    p {
                        text-align: right;
                    }

                </style>
                <div>
                    Kepada Yth., <br/>
                    Kepala Kepolisian Republik Indonesia <br/>
                    di Tempat. <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    Dengan ini saya ingin mengajukan permohonan pengiriman barang <br/>
                <div>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <p>Jakarta, 22 Januari 2022 </p>
                </div>
                    <table class="demo-table3">
```

The output for this code is:

[image]

How can I hide the HTML elements on the output text?

Answer (score 0):

Since CSS and HTML can be put into one files altogether, maybe try to add `html` in opening and closing so all html fields will be hidden.

```
<html>
                <style type="text/css">
                    .demo-table3 th,
                    .demo-table3 td {
                        width:1000px;
                        padding:20px;
                        top: 50%;
                        left: 50%;
                        margin-top: -120px;
                        margin-left: -220px;
                        text-align: center;
                        border: 0px;
                        padding: 7px 17px;
                    }

                    p {
                        text-align: right;
                    }

                </style>
                <div>
                    Kepada Yth., <br/>
                    Kepala Kepolisian Republik Indonesia <br/>
                    di Tempat. <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    Dengan ini saya ingin mengajukan permohonan pengiriman barang <br/>
                <div>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <p>Jakarta, 22 Januari 2022 </p>
                </div>
                    <table class="demo-table3">
</html>
```

For further reading please refer to [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_html.asp)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).